# Multiple definitions of a z-score

Tags: statistics

I am re-learning statistical fundamentals [which is quite awesome btw], and had a question around the different definitions of a z-score.

The two formulas (forgive me for the lack of formatting, I'm old school) I have seen are:

$$z = \frac{x - \mu}{\sigma}$$

and:

$$z = \frac{x_{bar} - \mu_{x,bar}}{\sigma / \sqrt{n}}$$

As I was taught, sample vars are $x_{bar}$ for mean and $s$ for standard deviation. For a population, you've got the greek letters, mu and sigma.

However, there is an actual mathematical difference in the denominator of the second definition, which is confusing to me. Obviously I understand the need to alter a formula to fit the n of an array, but if I were to find a z-score for an array of size 3000, what does the "sample" vs "population" tag matter? The size is greater than 30.

When does one use the first formula vs the second?

Comment: I believe the point is that you never actually know $\mu$ and $\sigma$, in practice. But the larger your sample, the better your estimates. The $\sqrt n$ affects the $z$-score to reflect this. It certainly would matter if you had a sample of $3000$ rather than $30$.